# How to import React component from node_modules without using babel

Tags: reactjs, git, babeljs, jsx, git-submodules

I can not import a React component from a different repo.

Steps I followed:

1. added the repo as submodule: `git submodule add <remote-url>`
2. added a symlink: `npm link` (name of the repo is "submodule-repo" )

I can see created module in node_modules of the main project.

```
mainReactProject 
  /.git
  /node_modules
     /submodule-repo
        /node_modules
        /public
        /src
            /theButton
                /theButton.js 
        /...
```

When I try to import the component file as:

`import newButton from 'submodule-repo/sec/theButton/theButton'`

I receive an error:

`Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (7:9):`

When I searched for it most people say configure babel. However I do not even use babel in both projects. Nevertheless I tried but creating .babelrc, installing and adding

```
{
   "plugins": [
       ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"]
   ]
}
```

or

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

also did not work. Should I install all babel packages to make this work or is there a way to not to use babel at all?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? If so, would you please share?

Comment: Nope, I ended up using mono repo.